# How do you change the icon of @state var to a touch id icon from SF Symbols?

Tags: swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct swiftui_menu_barApp: App {
    // 1
    @State var currentNumber: String = "1"
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        // 2
        MenuBarExtra(currentNumber, systemImage: "\(currentNumber).circle") {
            // 3
            Button("One") {
                currentNumber = "1"
            }
            Button("Two") {
                currentNumber = "2"
            }
            Button("Three") {
                currentNumber = "3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't get this to work since I put touch id instead of 1, but it gave me an error. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example code to display the `touch id` icon from SF Symbols.
I suggest you read the basics of SwiftUI to progress your understanding of programming with SwiftUI, eg: [your code](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-menu-bar-app/)

```
 @main
 struct TestMacApp: App {
     @State var currentIcon: String = "touchid"
     
     var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             // for testing
             HStack {
                 Text(currentIcon)
                 Image(systemName: currentIcon)
             }
         }
         MenuBarExtra(currentIcon, systemImage: currentIcon) {
             Button("One") { currentIcon = "1.circle" }
             Button("Two") { currentIcon = "2.circle" }
             Button("Three") { currentIcon = "3.circle" }
             Button("Touch ID") { currentIcon = "touchid" }
             Button("Face ID") { currentIcon = "faceid" }
         }
     }
 }
```